# How do you check if all of the labels from an array are out of form?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I'm making some kind of a game, where cubes appear, they fall down, you press on them, they then appear at the position they appeared before, the higher your score is, the faster the cubes go down. How do I check, if all of the cubes are out of the form? I tried making a bool, but it doesn't seem to work, here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Label [] kubeliai = new Label [5];
    Random pos = new Random();
    int poz = 100;
    Timer kritimo_laikrodis = new Timer();
    int kritimo_greitis = 1;
    int paspaudimu_skaicius = 0;
    int kritimo_didinimas = 0;
    Label paspaudimai = new Label();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kubeliai.Length; i++)
        {
            kubeliai[i] = new Label();
            Controls.Add(kubeliai[i]);
            kubeliai[i].Top = 50;
            kubeliai[i].Left = poz;
            poz += pos.Next(50, 200);
            kubeliai[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            kubeliai[i].Height = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Width = 20;
            kubeliai[i].Click += new EventHandler(kubelio_clickas);
        }

        Controls.Add(paspaudimai);
        paspaudimai.Left = 850;
        paspaudimai.Top = 30;
        paspaudimai.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14);
        paspaudimai.Text = "Taskai : 0";

        kritimo_laikrodis.Interval = 50;
        kritimo_laikrodis.Tick += new EventHandler(laikrodis);
        kritimo_laikrodis.Enabled = true;
    }
    void kubelio_clickas (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)sender).Top = 50;
        paspaudimu_skaicius += 1;
        kritimo_didinimas += 1;
        if (kritimo_didinimas == 5)
        {
            kritimo_didinimas = 0;
            kritimo_greitis += 1;
        }
        paspaudimai.Text = string.Format("Taskai: {0}", paspaudimu_skaicius);
    }
    void laikrodis (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kubeliai.Length; i++)
        {
            kubeliai[i].Top += kritimo_greitis;
        }
        bool visi_iskrito_is_zaidimo_lauko = kubeliai.All(kubeliai => kubeliai.Left >= this.Height == true);
        if (visi_iskrito_is_zaidimo_lauko)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("YOU LOST!", "LOSER!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How do I check, if all of the cubes are out of the form?"  What does that even mean?  Can you make your question clearer?

Comment: I have tagged winforms. When you're trying to make something with winforms you create a form. I have mentioned that the cubes go down and they go out of the form, so that means, that their position is lower than you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the labels X positions to the Forms Y positions

Try to change

```
 (kubeliai => kubeliai.Left >= this.Height == true);
```

to

```
 (kubeliai => kubeliai.Top >= this.Height);
```

Comment: I hurts my eye every time I see this: (kubeliai => kubeliai.Top >= this.Height == true); No need to add that "== true". It's a boolean expression already.

Comment: thanks, I'm kinda new to programming, currently doing a course, thanks anyway